# Creating Django project on server with nginx

Tags: django, webserver

We have a dev server with the internal hostname `dev1.internal.blah.com` running nginx. I'm trying to create a test Django project `testproject` from the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) on this server. I access this server by ssh-ing into it.

So on this server I installed Django, created a new directory, issued `django-admin startproject mysite` within it, then issued `python manage.py runserver 8765` and got the 
success message `Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8765/`

Now how would I access the `http://127.0.0.1:8765` site from a browser? I tried using `http://dev1.internal.blah.com:8765` but got a `This site can't be reached` error message.

If I try `curl http://127.0.0.1:8765` from the terminal, I see the correct html being rendered.

The nginx www directory is located at `/usr/share/nginx/html` if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django development server runs on port 8000 on the IP address 127.0.0.1, but note that that IP address is accessible only from your own server.

To make the `runserver` viewable to others, use either its own IP address or 0.0.0.0. or :: with IPv6 enabled.

So, you should probably run it like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8765
```

Comment: I tried that - going to `http://dev1.internal.blah.com:8765` results in a `Bad Request (400)` page, and in the terminal I see `Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8765/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[14/Feb/2018 19:45:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 26`

Comment: So, the runserver is working as it should but you yourself said that the domain `dev1.internal.blah.com` is internal so I'm not sure how would you expect to access it publicly from your browser? You could probably create a VPN connection to the server or set up a public domain.